# Custom DataGrid with retention of the style

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-style

I use C# WPF and [ModernWPF](https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf) theme.
I want to use a CustomDataGrid (because I need multiple selection). Source: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3140

The solution still works with ModernWPF, but the datagrid is in the "classical / old" style. Is there a way to reapply the style from ModernWPF?

**minimal demo project:**

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
    <Grid>
        <local:CustomDataGrid 
            AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" />
    </Grid>
```

ViewModel.cs

```cs
public partial class ViewModel :ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        public DataTable _data;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            var currentData = new DataTable();
            currentData.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            currentData.Columns.Add("BooleanValue", typeof(bool));


            //Two rows
            DataRow firstRow = currentData.NewRow();
            DataRow secondRow = currentData.NewRow();

            firstRow[0] = "Text1";
                firstRow[1] = true;
            
            secondRow[0] = "Text2"; 
                secondRow[1] = false;

            currentData.Rows.Add(firstRow);
            currentData.Rows.Add(secondRow);

            _data = currentData;
        }
    }
```

and the customDataGrid:

```cs
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
        public CustomDataGrid()
            => SelectionChanged += CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged;

        void CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            => SelectedItemsList = SelectedItems;
        #region SelectedItemsList

        public IList SelectedItemsList
        {
            get => (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsListProperty);
            set => SetValue(SelectedItemsListProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsListProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItemsList", typeof(IList), typeof(CustomDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(propertyChangedCallback: null));

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: I would be inclined to have an item viewmodel with an isselected property and work with that rather than what you're doing there. Add a column if it really must be a datable.

Comment: indeed, it would be possible. Still interested in how to reapply a theme :-)

Comment: Default styles will have a key equal to the type they apply to. So you can use based on to set the style of your control to the default for datagrid. Roughly BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Datagrid}}"

Comment: yes, something like that seems to work fine:
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CustomDataGridStyle" TargetType="local:CustomDataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <local:CustomDataGrid
            Style="{StaticResource CustomDataGridStyle}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"/>
    </Grid>